# on text selection at webView

Tags: android, webview

I need to catch on text selection event in webview. In standart webview when I select text appears action bar with menu. Can I get on select listener or override onselect actionbar menu?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Contextual Action Bars. Here's the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) and here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#tutorial_contextualmenu).